# Equations on generic algebraic stuctures.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Is there a general theory that studies the solution of equations on structures with a binary operation like, for example,  Magmas, Quasigroups, Semigroups, Monoids, Loops and Groups from the most general  point of view?

If there isn't a single theory, then is there  a specific "theory of equations" for every structure as above?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [Universal Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra)?

Comment: @yatima2975 I don't know if this can help me. If yes explain me why please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no known axioms for a magma, and you don't have an explicit representation of the magma, there's literally no way to solve for an equation. Using no axioms means not being able to restrict the problem to a class of algebras, either, unless you're studying a process that generates algebras with interesting solution properties that don't reduce to axioms on the class. The question is not whether it's possible to research a thing, but what reason there is to suspect there's any metastructure to solutions of equations that doesn't depend on the algebras themselves having structure. What are the semantics of the questions, the motivation?

Comment: What do you mean with "reperesentation"? Anyways your answer is not clear for me: please I need a more easy answer, I'm not so good with "semantic", "metastructures" and I don't even know what you mean with "process that generates algebras". With Axiom I think you mean Associativity, identity ecc. on a magma, it is right? So if without axioms (Magmas) is impossible to solve anything I'm interested in specific cases like groups or monoids too.

Comment: Representation in the loose sense of an interface as explicit as a multiplication table. If you're looking for a new kind of space, you might require abnormal structures, so results you were required to obtain about those structures carry extra semantics. Metastructure here is emergent complexity, consequences of the magma's structure that give the solutions of its equations structure, patternicity. If you had a rule for filling out a multiplication table that had room for variations, that would be a process for generating algebra. Yes, those are some desirable axioms.

Comment: MMh Maybe is better now, but if I want to go deeper from where I must start? What should I study first?

Comment: @MphLee Well, what made you interested in this question?

Comment: I had a problem and I wanted to find powerfull tools: Give a set $M$ and an associative binary operation $*$ (in some cases with identity and/or inverse elements) I want to find a set of elements $x\in X \subset M$ that make a generic statement $x*a_0*a_1*a_2*...a_n=a_{n+1}$ true in that structure. Or maybe even more complex equations, wher $x$ appears two or more times

Comment: Aha. Well, you might want to look at Green's relations. These allow you to treat semigroups in terms of ring theory, which relates the question in many cases to the study of solutions of polynomials. Why did you need such general tools for this problem?

Comment: Is a bit hard, but I'll study it, thanks. Now I'm gonna wait some days for other answers. By the way, I'm interested in this because I'm studyng a structure on a set $M$ generated by equations on a structure $\langle M,* \rangle $ . To be precise I'm studyng (xD "playng" because It's an hobby) the partial orders on $M$ generated by equations on $\langle M,* \rangle$ and since I'm a newbie I asked for help regarding where to look and what to study.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9297/discussion-between-mphlee-and-loki-clock)

Comment: @MphLee Certainly!